# how to delete a specific category from my bar chart in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to remove category NA, so that it shows the percentages of the other categories clearly, which command can I use?

The chart follows below

```
ggplot(data = DADO)+ 
  geom_bar(aes(x=X85, y=(..count../sum(..count..)),fill=X85), col="black") +
  ggtitle("Gráfico 84", subtitle = "Por qual razão você não participou de nenhuma capacitação nos últimos 10 anos?") + 
  theme_classic() +
  ylab("Proporção") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())  + 
  xlab(" ") +
  labs(fill="Legenda") + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 1, 0.05))  + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should remove them altogether from your dataframe.

```
DADO_NO_NA <- na.omit(DADO)
```

or

```
DADO_NO_NA <- na.exclude(DADO)
```

or even directly in your ggplot call.

```
ggplot(data = na.omit(DADO))+ 
  geom_bar(aes(x=X85, y=(..count../sum(..count..)),fill=X85), col="black") +
  ggtitle("Gráfico 84", subtitle = "Por qual razão você não participou de nenhuma capacitação nos últimos 10 anos?") + theme_classic() +
  ylab("Proporção") +  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())  + xlab(" ")+labs(fill="Legenda")+scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 1, 0.05))  + scale_fill_brewer(     palette = "Set1")
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to remove the NA's from the variable X85 you can use the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
DADO %>%
  filter(!is.na(X85))%>%
  ggplot(data = .)+ 
  geom_bar(aes(x=X85, y=(..count../sum(..count..)),fill=X85), col="black") +
  ggtitle("Gráfico 84", subtitle = "Por qual razão você não participou de nenhuma capacitação nos últimos 10 anos?") + theme_classic() +
  ylab("Proporção") +  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())  + xlab(" ")+labs(fill="Legenda")+scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 1, 0.05))  + scale_fill_brewer(     palette = "Set1")
```

Comment: Error in filter(., !is.na(X85)) : objeto 'X85' não encontrado

Comment: Eu acho que não precisa do ponto, apenas `filter(!is.na(X85))`

Comment: Não coloquei o ponto não =( , o erro saiu assim no console ..

script : igualmente seu codigo acima
console :  Error in filter(., !is.na(X85)) : objeto 'X85' não encontrado